# Как выводить сообщения от with?

Tags: laravel

Как выводить в шаблоне сообщения, которые создаются строчками `with('success', '...')`?

Comment: `session('success')  | session()->get('success')  |  Session::get('success')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В blade шаблонизаторе выведи

```
 @if (session('success'))
     {{ session('success') }}
 @endif
```